# Here Maps on Ubuntu touch only displays a blank screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps

After using "Here Maps" on Ubuntu touch for a while, the app started to have a problem starting. Instead of showing me the user interface, I was presented with nothing but a white screen and a loading bar on top, that after hitting the edge of the scree would disappear.

Solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make "Here Maps" work again, you have to clear it's cache (Why this has to be done is beyond me).

To do it, just open the terminal app and delete the dir containing the cached data:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/com.nokia.heremaps
```

The app should work fine afterwards. You will loose any saved data though.

**Word of caution:** Be *very* careful when working with the `rm -r` command.